# how to add munit support in eclipse

Tags: unit-testing, mule, munit

I know this link adds munit support in Studio

http://studio.mulesoft.org/r4/munit

but is there another plugin for eclipse? Confirming as it specifically says Studio plugin

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That link is correct.
MUnit Studio Plugin, requires the Studio platform to work.

It hasn't been designed to work in a plain vanilla Eclipse. Then again I reckon that if you manage to install all the required plugins it should work but you'll end up with  basically with Studio again.

HTH

Comment: so basically there is no plugin yet in eclipse **just** for munit

Comment: You need a plugin only if you want to use the XML variant of MUnit, you do not need anything if you want to use the Java variant. I personally think the Java variant has lower learning curve especially if you are already used to JUnit and mocking libraries